# Viewport meta tag has no effect in mobile safari

Tags: css, mobile, viewport

I have a website that has a menu element that is exactly 900 pixels wide.
I want the 900 pixels to be scaled to the width of mobile screens using the viewport tag - but this doesn't seem to work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

My CSS has only one element that has any width, this is the top menu:

```
body {
    background-color:#6C88FF;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

menu {
    background-image: url(../images/menu.png);
    width: 900px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
```

I would expect the website to fit nicely in the browser, but on phones the viewport is too small and on ipad it is too big. How do I get the 900-pixel wide website to fit nicely in any mobile viewport?

[image: Viewport misbehaves]

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/eerk/pen/NrGQqX)

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how viewport works. I have added a screenshot that shows the result I am after. How else would I achieve this? The menu is always displayed as wide as it is (900px), and always fills the entire width of the device.

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `initial-scale=1` from the `viewport` meta tag.

> The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is
>   first loaded.

In short, it tells the browser to load the page in defined sizes, in other words with `initial-scale=1` each pixel of the page will get one pixel of the viewport.

Since you have your sizes defined in `px` units it prevents the 'scaling' that you are expecting.

Comment: This has no effect :( I have added a codepen. I don't want to use percentages. The whole point is that I know my website will be exactly 900pixels wide.... #confused

Comment: The codepen also has `initial-scale=1` set in it, so it will not 'scale'.

Comment: Oops. I removed it, but... I don't see any difference? See  [codepen in full view](http://s.codepen.io/eerk/debug/NrGQqX)

Comment: You can also set the width to be 900px if you have a constant width for your page, so `<meta name="viewport" content="width=900,  user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any difference? Even setting initial scale to 2 or 0.1 has no effect. Is this some kind of bug, or am I testing it the wrong way?

Comment: How are you testing? I think the viewport <meta> won't have an effect if it's inside an iframe. Most of these sites like codepen, jsbin, etc. often display the output in an iframe, even if you display it "fullscreen".

Comment: Good point, I just discovered that safari and chrome's 'responsive mode' do not show the meta sizing behavior correctly! That was half of the problem.
Also, I found out that sizing the whole website in pixels and then removing the viewport tag, scales the website to the size of the mobile screen.... so the solution was actually to leave out the viewport tag...

Answer (score 0):

You could set the the viewport width to 900px and let the device handle scaling for you.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900px, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I have set the viewport tag to 900px but I don't see any difference. See [codepen](http://codepen.io/eerk/pen/NrGQqX)

Comment: iPad have only just started respecting viewport width settings on iOS 10. Its a pain for me because I _wanted_ the ipad to act like a desktop browser, and only the phones be scaled. Now I have to set the viewport meta tag in javascript after first observing what the default device-with is.